# CLI command to get a list of API Gateway APIs by lambda authorizer name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am upgrading Nodejs lambda runtime for some of our API Gateway lambda authorizers. I need to know if there is a way using AWS CLI to get a list of all API Gateway APIs which are using a particular lambda authorizer so that I could test all those APIs before upgrading the Nodejs runtime.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like the output contains authorizer unfortunately, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html

Comment: @JeremyThompson I just confirmed that it doesn't show the authorizer name or arn.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how many requests like this are accepted as feature requests. AWS are very receptive especially to enterprise customers... in your AWS account raise a request.

Answer (score 1):

I had a chat with AWS support and they confirmed at the time of writing there is no direct way of getting the list of rest APIs by authorizer. However, there could be 2 ways to achieve this.

1. When we create a Lambda authorizer in apigw, we have 2 options: either set a Lambda Invoke Role at apigw level itself, or let apigw add a resource policy on this Lambda to allow our api to invoke it as authorizer. If its the later, in the Lambda's resource policy, we should see the APIs that are currently invoking this function. But if we have used Lambda Invoke Role in apigw, this will not help
2. The second way via CLI or SDK is the command `aws apigateway get-authorizers --rest-api-id` to get the details of all authorizers attached to a particular API. We can run this command for all APIs in our region and for those APIs which use this Lambda as authorizer, we will see that Lambda's ARN in the `authorizerUri` of the response

So instead of using CLI command I decided to write a small Python script using Boto3 as I didn't want to run the CLI command for many rest apis in our environment. The script returns the list of all the rest apis which use my lambda `api-authorizer` as the authorizer. This may not be the most efficient code as this was my first crack at Python, but it does the job.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')
restApis = client.get_rest_apis(limit=500)
apiList = restApis['items']

for i in apiList:
  #print('api: ', i['name'], 'id: ', i['id'])
  authorizers = client.get_authorizers(restApiId=i['id'])
  authorizerList = authorizers['items']
  #print(len(authorizerList), 'authorizers found', '\n')
  
  for j in authorizerList:
    if 'api-authorizer' not in j['authorizerUri']:
      continue
    else: 
      print(i['name'])
```